# Activate "ETH over USB" on Linux [SIMPLE TRICK]

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I need to modify the kernel to enable the USB networking ability for my network of development boards. (currently 1master & 10servers) we need to use usb connections for networking functionalities.

My question: is it possible to modify the linux kernel without compiling a whole image from scratch. We are now developing a network of mashines and are thinking ahead, doing some planning, to reduce our workload in the future and for avoiding the need to reinstall all the OSes on the whole network. Optimally we would never need to reinstall an image /only reboot a mashine and do meaningful changes on the kernel over ssh. Metaphoricallly speaking: we need to be able to transform a prototype airplane into a super jet, without ever landing.

I already went through a decent amount of research for aprox. 1 week and I think the solution is something like this:

1.
https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/USB_NET_CDCETHER.html

2.
https://serverfault.com/questions/821245/how-to-hook-an-ethernet-over-usb-connection-up-to-the-host-network

3.
https://nxp.gitbook.io/d2x/software/d2x-application/enabling-usb-network

4.
and a lot more... (these are the most relevant ones)

(We will modify and play around with the kernels in the future, I just finished my last course of my ITCP School, I just picked up Programming at University and I will very probably go deeper into Kernels in the near future)

For now I only need to change this one thing and I will surely work on kernels later on my path.
(and hopefully get someone on board that has relevant experience with the linux kernel)

The main goal is to activate "ETH over USB" for a simple trick, in order to get rid of obsolete periphery in the future. (here&now: get rid of the eth port) We are passing little data volume over ssh. (from one master to multiple servers)

What I already know/the keywords that I'm using for further research are:

1.
I need to modify the "drivers/net/usb/Kconfig"
CONFIG_USB_NET_CDCETHER

2.
cdc-ecm class for ethernet over usb

3.
Enabling USB RNDIS Support

The problem split in 2 is:

1. Can I modify a kernel without the need of reinstalling the whole OS
2. How to activate USB Networking(eth over usb)

Thank you in advance,

Best Regards,
Annony

Comment: If you don't want to recompile the kernel, you'll need to do it with loadable kernel modules.

Comment: `CONFIG_USB_NET_CDCETHER` Sooo, why do you think it's disabled? You are asking XY question - do you care about modyfing kernel? Why all the text? Just load the module `cdc_ether`, it's right there, you don't have to do anthing. `How to activate USB Networking(eth over usb)` You have to plug in the usb modem. And load the module, or have it loaded automatically (udev). No more actions are really needed.